# Make netrw not close previous buffer but open a new buffer

Tags: netrw

I have `netrw_browse_split` set to 4, so typing `<Enter>` on a file on netrw will open it on the previous window.
But if the previous window have a file, it will be closed.

How can I make opening a file with netrw on the previous window not close the file on that window, but instead open it on a new buffer, so that I can have several files open on a single window but swap between then with netrw?

Comment: Are you sure the previous file buffer is *closed*? If you type `:ls` after the "replacement", do you still see your old file?

Comment: But it asks for saving modifications first, and if I say no, it ignores the changes. How can I make it not ignore changes?

Comment: I just found out that I just had to `set hidden`.